# Ionic2 google maps Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

my project woks good without google maps plugin , when i install it and try to build i get:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzc;
```

when i create a new project and install the plugin it runs well so i think one of my plugins conflict with it

ionic info:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.6
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.1.1

System:

    Node       : v6.10.3
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 3.10.10
```

cordova plugin list:

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.4 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.4 "PushPlugin"
plugin.google.maps 1.3.9 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing version 1.3.9. Worked for me:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps@1.3.9 --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
```